# any good way to create a generic property implementation in 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I was reviewing this url on generics in C# but I'm unclear on how to implement the generic implementation I have in mind:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

I need to create a custom KeyValuePair class for downstream serialization.  Downstream json serialization converts a native .net Dictionary into a generic javascript object which adds complexity and overhead so I need to create a custom KeyvaluePair class.

However, I want to make this custom KeyValuePair class generic so the key or value can either be an int or string. What would be the most elegant way to implement this in C#? The following code is incorrect but demonstrates what I'm looking for:

```
public class KeyValuePair
{
    public <T> Key { get; set; }
    public <T> Value { get; set; }
}
```

I did some googling and the only references I found were a few years old and the implementations seemed a bit hacky.  Not sure if there's a better way to do this in 2017....

Comment: the `<T>` goes after the class name and then in the rest of it just use `T` just as if it was a type name

Comment: You can look into custom (de)serialisers. That would be the better route rather than doing this.

Comment: This really reads like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - your underlying issue really sounds like it should be solvable with the built in `Dictionary<T, U>` or `KeyValuePair<T, U>` types - you should ask about that instead - ie detail what serialisation issues you've actually had when using those types etc.

Comment: Instead of <T> in you code - you can use dynamic. But i'm still not getting what do you want to achieve. Probably dynamic is not "the best" solution

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation works perfectly:

```
public class MyCustomKeyValuePair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Key { get; set; }
    public T2 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the pointer @litelite!

Comment: How would that be more helpful than just using a `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`?

Comment: The framework's built in `KayValuePair` is an immutable struct. That's the only difference I can see. Perhaps the OP can shade some lite on this.